# Unexpected stress concentration results

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses, solidworks

I've run some stress simulations but I keep getting some unexpected results. I have 3 parts connected using 4 bolts as follows:

[image]

A torque of 1N is applied to the hole on the right to simulate a hung weight. After running several stress simulations, the two highest points of stress concentration appear to locate at the bottom of the part with the hole, specifically at the end of the fillet on the outer surface:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there are two hotspots along the end of the fillet -- equal distance away from the edges. Does anyone know what might cause the stress at these two locations?

EDIT: Here's an overlay of the mesh over the stress hotspot:

[image]

Comment: you need to include a screenshot of your mesh - this most likely a mesh convergence issue cauaed by not having enough elements at the transition from simple planar to bendy geometry.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I've added an overlay of the mesh over the stress hotspots. The transition looks fairly alright, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Thanks, @John M. Can you confirm if the hotspots are where the part contacts the edge between the countersunk hole and the flat surface of the lower bracket?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Indeed it is! The hotspot disappears when the hole is filled. I guess I'll have to move it out of the hole? Thanks!

Comment: No problem - there will always be a hotspot where faces meet at an edge like this - you could reduce it by adding a fillet to the outside edge of the countersink, and adding more elements in the relevant area, but the benefit would be minimal. I'd personally just add some elements so that the distance the hotspot effects spread is reduced, and then ignore the values very close to these.